# Unpowered Analog test simulation

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb

I am analyzing a large circuit and I want to perform an **unpowered analog test** simulation of the circuit (as it is a large schematic, i have divided it into various modules/pages). My aim is to do a pre-calculation or a simulation of an ***unpowered analog test of this circuit*** before an In-circuit test (ICT) in series production.

One of the modules looks like the below schematic.  **With a simulation**, ***I want to know, if all components in circuit are present and the values of the components are correct.***

For this modeule, I have only 2 test points for this particular sensor Module, TP_100 and TP_200 availble during the testing in series production. One test point (say TP_100) has influence from the other components in the same network which is near to the other test point (say TP_200).

But I dont have an idea, *How to perform a simulation or pre-calculation for an In-Circuit Test?*

edit: It is meant for an unpowered analog test, not an EOL test to check the functionality of the circuit, but to check the value of individual component or cluster of components.

[image]

Comment: Is this really, really true: *I have only 2 test points, TP_100 and TP_200 availble during the testing*

Comment: I have more than 200 TP in the PCB, but for this particular Sensor Module I have only 2 TPs.

Comment: So ground and Sense_In are unavailable?

Comment: "But I dont have an idea, How to perform a simulation... for an **In-Circuit Test**?" - Why would it be different from a normal simulation?

Comment: they are available as well. Sense_in is something like a temp sensor input. 
Out is  to connected to the µC.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, In ICT testing, the components are tested for their values. Sometimes values is measured as impedences, for eg if capa or ind is present in the network, which is an obvious in large circuit.  Also, in ICT testing, only a stimulus voltage is given across the component or across a cluster of components. It is different than the end of line (EOL) tetsing with a flashed µC. ICT doesnt check the functionality of the circuit.

Comment: "Sometimes values is measured as impedences" - so you want the simulation to output the expected impedance at the test point?

Comment: Yes, that is right too, because if the impedence measured at one TP is always the same , then I can assume that a cluster of components are present. But I am not sure how to measure that, because many network is connected complexly.